# Could not load file or assembly "System.Threading.Tasks,Version=1.5.11.0.." In Silverlight Application

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, signalr.client

I am working on Silverlight Application and trying to create SignalR Client Code in my application but getting error as below when trying to start Hub Connection .
I have instlaled all packages like "Microsoft.Aspnet.SignalR.client", "Microsoft.Bcl" but getting error

> ERROR
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Below is sample code from my application.

```
Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim myHubConnections As HubConnection
        Dim myHubProxy As IHubProxy
        Dim CurrentContext As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
        Dim message As String = ""
        myHubConnections = New HubConnection("http://gcrmdev0.goldcrm2.com/GSPWebServices-DAK/signalr/hubs")
        myHubProxy = myHubConnections.CreateHubProxy("signalRHub")

        'myHubProxy.On("NotifyAgent",

        txtCaseNotes1.Text = "Notifications Received from Server"

        myHubConnections.Start().Wait()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format code by indenting four spaces, or using the {} buttons to format selected text as code.

Answer (score 0):

It may because of the wrong app.config entries. Clean up the app.config file by removing the wrong entries. When adding the NuGet package to a project that is consumed by another project with a different target framework you might see this kinds of errors.

[Check here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx) the Issue number 6 and 9.